# How to generate a QR code that redirects to a URL?

Tags: android, bitmap

I've been working with a QR generator app, and it works fine with me.

My question is, how to generate a QR code that will redirect to a website after being scanned by a QR reader?

This is my QR generator code which generates only simple text:

```
Bitmap getQRCode(Context context, String type, String value) throws WriterException {
    BitMatrix bitMatrix;

    try {
        bitMatrix = new MultiFormatWriter().encode(value, BarcodeFormat.DATA_MATRIX.QR_CODE, QR_DIM, QR_DIM, null);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return null;
    }

    int bitMatrixHeight = bitMatrix.getHeight();
    int bitMatrixWidth = bitMatrix.getWidth();
    int pixels[] = new int[bitMatrixHeight * bitMatrixWidth];

    for (int y = 0; y < bitMatrixHeight; y++) {
        int offset = y * bitMatrixWidth;

        for (int x = 0; x < bitMatrixWidth; x++) {

            pixels[offset + x] = bitMatrix.get(x, y) ?
                    context.getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeBlackColor):context.getResources().getColor(R.color.QRCodeWhiteColor);
        }
    }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, 500, 0, 0, bitMatrixWidth, bitMatrixHeight);
    return bitmap;
}
```

Thanks you guys.

Answer (score 1):

Use
https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen then
you can read the QR code and  open a web view using the result.
I haven't tried it yet but I hope this helps

Comment: @MarGin Thank you so much, apparently when you just generate QR with URL it redirects automatically if the QR reader supports it, so the QR itself have nothing to do with redirection. I tried to read a URL QR from Samsung Bixby and it automatically redirect me to the link, and tried on another QR Reader and it just showed that it's a URL